Citing multiple works of same author at different positions in one sentence in APA 7 style
A sentence has to mention the author's name and cite two specific works of the author. Which version is correct in APA 7?

Cardon et al. were able to demonstrate in two studies that executive
functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in
mathematical modeling (2009) and problem-solving (2019).
Cardon et al. (2009, 2019) were able to demonstrate in two studies
that executive functions are particularly strongly associated with
abilities in mathematical modeling (2009) and problem-solving
(2019).
Cardon et al. were able to demonstrate in two studies that executive functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in
mathematical modeling (Cardon et al., 2009) and problem-solving
(Cardon et al., 2019).
Cardon et al. (2009, 2019) were able to demonstrate in two studies that executive functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in
mathematical modeling (Cardon et al., 2009) and problem-solving
(Cardon et al., 2019).

A colleague told me to go with #4, but this seems a little much.

Either

Executive functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in mathematical modeling and problem-solving (Cardon et al. 2009, 2019).

or, if you insist that the name appears in the main text and not in parentheses,

Cardon et al. (2009, 2019) showed that executive functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in mathematical modeling and problem-solving.

You don't need to say "two studies" as that is obvious from the number of citations. You can also save some words by saying "showed" instead of "were able to demonstrate."

I agree "two studies" isn't necessary, but many papers report multiple studies; and a "single study" can often be reported in multiple papers.

In APA 7, I have never seen a stranded year-only citation, #1 and #2 look like errors to me. I agree with toby544's first suggestion, or if I wanted to mention the authors, I would consider (also including Toby's suggestions about word choice):

Cardon and colleagues [demonstrated] executive functions are particularly strongly associated with abilities in mathematical modeling (Cardon et al., 2009) and problem-solving (Cardon et al., 2019).


Coauthors are not necessarily colleagues, so I'd tend to prefer "Cardon and collaborators".

@Anyon I think this is really fine hair splitting, but I agree "collaborators" is also acceptable.

I'd accept any of the above, as it's clear which citations are relevant to which parts of the text. Generally, reference nuances like this have no impact on outcome, whether this is for publishing or an academic submission. Indeed, for the former, they have a team who will reformat anyway.
